# NSIS MUI LANGUAGE ID

Tags: localization, nsis

I need to write selected language into the file in installation folder in order to localize application.

I know how to display select language page, but I want to write id of selected language inside the file.
In section which is executed during MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES i have this:

```
 FileOpen $0 "$DESKTOP\xy.txt" w     #Just testing, will go inside install directory later
 FileWrite $0 "$LANGUAGE" 
 FileClose $0
```

but it's not working. When $LANGUAGE is replaced by other string it creates file and places the string inside it.
Any suggestion please? Thank you.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure FileOpen is indeed creating and opening a file?

Comment: well if I add messageBox MB_OK "Now We are Creating Hello_world.txt at Desktop!"  in front of FileOpen it creates the file otherwise it is buggy and it doesnt creates the file I dont understand why. Cannot be it by MUI ?

Comment: Weird. Are you sure compiler runs without errors? Maybe it fails and you are in fact running an older exe. ¿?

Comment: When I put it inside INSTDIR which was also set as OutPath everything is working

Comment: Maybe you are running installer as a different windows user (administrator)? In that case, maybe $DESKTOP points to a different directory. Try displaying it `MessageBox MB_OK "$DESKTOP\xy.txt`.